# How to break datepicker into a three three month grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

```js
$('#calendar').datepicker({
  numberOfMonths: 12,
  minDate: new Date(2021, 1 - 1, 1),
  maxDate: new Date(2021, 12 - 1, 31),
  showButtonPanel: true,
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id='calendar'></div>
</div>
```

This shows all the months on one line.

How can I break datepicker into a 3-by-4 grid, e.g. this layout:

```
Jan Feb Mar
Apr May Jun
Jul Aug Sep
Oct Nov Dec
```

I tried adding multiple datepickers, but that's not working.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? What do you mean by breaking here?

Comment: i want to arrange months  like shown in link https://cdn.vertex42.com/calendars/images/yearly-calendar-template-any-year.png
not in single row so how do i add css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How `numberOfMonths` is used must be an array instead of a whole number to achieve the desired layout.

From the datepicker docs:

[image]

So based on that info, use `numberOfMonths` with an array of row and column values to get the desired grid/matrix.

```js
$('#calendar').datepicker({
  numberOfMonths: [4, 3], // 4 rows, 3 columns
  minDate: new Date(2021, 1 - 1, 1),
  maxDate: new Date(2021, 12 - 1, 31),
  showButtonPanel: true,
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id='calendar'></div>
</div>
```